# Trouble converting dataframe to json

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
                                                      2023-06-30      2022-06-30      2021-06-30      2020-06-30
Ordinary Shares Number                              7432000000.0    7464000000.0    7519000000.0    7571000000.0
Share Issued                                        7432000000.0    7464000000.0    7519000000.0    7571000000.0
Net Debt                                           12533000000.0   35850000000.0   43922000000.0   49751000000.0
Total Debt                                         59965000000.0   61270000000.0   67775000000.0   70998000000.0
Tangible Book Value                               128971000000.0   87720000000.0   84477000000.0   67915000000.0
...                                                          ...             ...             ...             ...
Cash Cash Equivalents And Short Term Investments  111262000000.0  104757000000.0  130334000000.0  136527000000.0
Other Short Term Investments                       76558000000.0   90826000000.0  116110000000.0  122951000000.0
Cash And Cash Equivalents                          34704000000.0   13931000000.0   14224000000.0   13576000000.0
Cash Equivalents                                   26226000000.0    5673000000.0    6952000000.0             NaN
Cash Financial                                      8478000000.0    8258000000.0    7272000000.0             NaN

[73 rows x 4 columns]
```

And I am trying to convert it to json in the following format:

```
{
    "2023-06-30": {
        "Ordinary Shares Number": "7432000000.0",
        ...
    },
    "2022-06-30": {
        "Ordinary Shares Number": "7464000000.0",
        ...
    },
    "2021-06-30": {
        "Ordinary Shares Number": "7519000000.0",
        ...
    },
    "2020-06-30": {
        "Ordinary Shares Number": "7571000000.0",
        ...
    }
}
```

However my attempts to convert it have ranged from bad to worse so I really have no idea what I'm doing.

My attempts are either giving my a very undesirable json format or a type error about the timestamps:

For example:

```
out = json.dumps({c: dict(zip(balance.index, balance[c])) for c in balance.columns}, indent=4)
print(out)
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/jesse_b/tools/stonk-db/stonkdb/__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/jesse_b/tools/stonk-db/stonkdb/__main__.py", line 32, in main
    out = json.dumps({c: dict(zip(balance.index, balance[c])) for c in balance.columns}, indent=4)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 431, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 376, in _iterencode_dict
    raise TypeError(f'keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, '
TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Timestamp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dict-comprehension:

```py
import json

# convert the columns to string before (if needed)
# df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)

out = json.dumps({c: dict(zip(df.index, df[c])) for c in df.columns}, indent=4)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "2023-06-30": {
        "Ordinary Shares Number": 7432000000.0,
        "Share Issued": 7432000000.0,
        "Net Debt": 12533000000.0,
        "Total Debt": 59965000000.0,
        "Tangible Book Value": 128971000000.0,
        "Cash Cash Equivalents And Short Term Investments": 111262000000.0,
        "Other Short Term Investments": 76558000000.0,
        "Cash And Cash Equivalents": 34704000000.0,
        "Cash Equivalents": 26226000000.0,
        "Cash Financial": 8478000000.0
    },
    "2022-06-30": {
        "Ordinary Shares Number": 7464000000.0,
        "Share Issued": 7464000000.0,
        "Net Debt": 35850000000.0,
        "Total Debt": 61270000000.0,
        "Tangible Book Value": 87720000000.0,
        "Cash Cash Equivalents And Short Term Investments": 104757000000.0,
        "Other Short Term Investments": 90826000000.0,
        "Cash And Cash Equivalents": 13931000000.0,
        "Cash Equivalents": 5673000000.0,
        "Cash Financial": 8258000000.0
    },
    "2021-06-30": {
        "Ordinary Shares Number": 7519000000.0,
        "Share Issued": 7519000000.0,
        "Net Debt": 43922000000.0,
        "Total Debt": 67775000000.0,
        "Tangible Book Value": 84477000000.0,
        "Cash Cash Equivalents And Short Term Investments": 130334000000.0,
        "Other Short Term Investments": 116110000000.0,
        "Cash And Cash Equivalents": 14224000000.0,
        "Cash Equivalents": 6952000000.0,
        "Cash Financial": 7272000000.0
    },
    "2020-06-30": {
        "Ordinary Shares Number": 7571000000.0,
        "Share Issued": 7571000000.0,
        "Net Debt": 49751000000.0,
        "Total Debt": 70998000000.0,
        "Tangible Book Value": 67915000000.0,
        "Cash Cash Equivalents And Short Term Investments": 136527000000.0,
        "Other Short Term Investments": 122951000000.0,
        "Cash And Cash Equivalents": 13576000000.0,
        "Cash Equivalents": NaN,
        "Cash Financial": NaN
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't tried that but it is giving me the same error that a few of my attempts did which is: `TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Timestamp`

Comment: @jesse_b You can convert the row with timestamp to string before converting to Json, e.g. `df.loc["Timestamp Row"] = df.loc["Timestamp Row", :].astype(str)`

Comment: apologies as I'm sure I'm missing something that is obvious to most but I'm pretty new to python.  Getting this:  `File "/home/jesse_b/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3655, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err` ; `KeyError: 'Timestamp Row'`

Comment: @jesse_b Or try to convert the columns to string: `df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)`

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much.  You're a gentleman, a scholar, and a breeder of fine horses.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve the same JSON structure by just setting the first column as the index of the DataFrame and then converting it to JSON using `df.to_json(orient='columns')`. In the `'columns'` orientation, the JSON takes the shape where each column in the DataFrame becomes a key, and the corresponding values are stored in an array under that key.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df.set_index(df.columns[0], inplace=True)
result = df.to_json(orient='columns')

parsed = json.loads(result)
print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4))
```

Prints

```
{
    "2023-06-30": {
        "Ordinary Shares Number": 7432000000.0,
        "Share Issued": 7432000000.0,
        "Net Debt": 12533000000.0,
        "Total Debt": 59965000000.0,
        "Tangible Book Value": 129000000000.0,
        "Cash Cash Equivalents": 111000000000.0,
        "Other Short Term Investme": 76558000000.0,
        "Cash And Cash Equivalents": 34704000000.0,
        "Cash Equivalents": 26226000000.0,
        "Cash Financial": 8478000000.0
    },
    "2022-06-30": {
        "Ordinary Shares Number": 7464000000.0,
        "Share Issued": 7464000000.0,
        "Net Debt": 35850000000.0,
        "Total Debt": 61270000000.0,
        "Tangible Book Value": 87720000000.0,
        "Cash Cash Equivalents": 105000000000.0,
        "Other Short Term Investme": 90826000000.0,
        "Cash And Cash Equivalents": 13931000000.0,
        "Cash Equivalents": 5673000000.0,
        "Cash Financial": 8258000000.0
    },
    "2021-06-30": {
        "Ordinary Shares Number": 7519000000.0,
        "Share Issued": 7519000000.0,
        "Net Debt": 43922000000.0,
        "Total Debt": 67775000000.0,
        "Tangible Book Value": 84477000000.0,
        "Cash Cash Equivalents": 130000000000.0,
        "Other Short Term Investme": 116000000000.0,
        "Cash And Cash Equivalents": 14224000000.0,
        "Cash Equivalents": 6952000000.0,
        "Cash Financial": 7272000000.0
    },
    "2020-06-30": {
        "Ordinary Shares Number": 7571000000.0,
        "Share Issued": 7571000000.0,
        "Net Debt": 49751000000.0,
        "Total Debt": 70998000000.0,
        "Tangible Book Value": 67915000000.0,
        "Cash Cash Equivalents": 137000000000.0,
        "Other Short Term Investme": 123000000000.0,
        "Cash And Cash Equivalents": 13576000000.0,
        "Cash Equivalents": null,
        "Cash Financial": null
    }
}
```